# JavaScript doesn't work in simple React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, docker, nginx

I am basing on a simple React app from https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose/tree/master/react-nginx but I made a few modifications and now the website is currently working except for the fact that the React logo is not spinning and when I inspect the website then I see "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app." what is expected behavior if I would have disabled js in the browser but I don't!  The file https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose/blob/master/react-nginx/public/index.html is responsible for this  tag. The main difference between my configuration and the https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose/tree/master/react-nginx is that I use unprivileged nginx image.

Furthermore when I enter the container and do `ls -la /usr/share/nginx/html` then I see below output:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jul 26 18:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jul 24 00:08 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  605 Jul 26 18:29 asset-manifest.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3870 Jul 26 18:29 favicon.ico
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  644 Jul 26 18:29 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5347 Jul 26 18:29 logo192.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9664 Jul 26 18:29 logo512.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  492 Jul 26 18:29 manifest.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   67 Jul 26 18:29 robots.txt
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jul 26 18:29 static
```

nginx.conf:

```
pid /tmp/nginx.pid;

events {}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    server {
        listen 8080 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/tls/tls.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/tls/tls.key;

        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri /index.html =404;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

        location = /50x.html {
          root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.4

# 1. For build React app
FROM node:20.2.0-bullseye-slim AS development

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to container
COPY package.json /app/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /app/package-lock.json

# Same as npm install
RUN npm ci && npm cache clean --force

COPY . /app

ENV CI=true
ENV PORT=3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]


FROM development AS build

RUN npm run build


FROM development as dev-envs

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
ENV NODE_ENV=development

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends git

RUN useradd -s /bin/bash -m vscode && \
groupadd docker && \
usermod -aG docker vscode

# Install Docker tools (cli, buildx, compose)
COPY --from=gloursdocker/docker / /

RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force
RUN npm install -g nodemon

CMD [ "nodemon", "--inspect=0.0.0.0:9229"]


## Nginx unprivileged debian image
FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1.25

## Switch to root user for setup
USER root

## Update apk and add curl
RUN apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y curl; \
    apt-get install -y npm;

# Copy config nginx
COPY --from=build /app/.nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Copy mime.types from nginx image
COPY --from=nginx:alpine /etc/nginx/mime.types /etc/nginx/mime.types

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

# Remove default nginx static assets
RUN rm -rf ./*

# Copy static assets from builder stage
COPY --from=build /app/build .

# Copy the /app dir from builder stage in order to be able to do the unit tests
COPY --from=build /app /test-app

## Expose port 8080
EXPOSE 8080

## Switch to non-root user
USER nginx

## Healthchecks
# TODO Later, when you move from the self-signed certificates delete "-k" flag
HEALTHCHECK --interval=30s --timeout=5s --start-period=5s --retries=3 \
    CMD curl -k -f https://localhost:8080 || exit 1
```

And the web source code is the same as in https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose/tree/master/react-nginx

Comment: 'when I inspect the website then I see "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app."' - Do you mean by inspecting the page source? That message being included in the source doesn't mean that JavaScript is disabled in the browser. It is *conditionally displayed* for HTML viewers that have JavaScript disabled.

Comment: In addition to my comment above, you should be testing your changes locally before attempting to deploy the ReactJS app with nginx. Also, your Dockerfile attempts to copy the React build output to the `/usr/share/nginx/html` directory on your machine, but the code to do so is commented out, so your changes will not be reflected when visiting the webapp. To deploy a ReactJS app  you need the build output, which creates a single page app. That output needs to be copied to a location specified by your nginx.conf file, in which the location is currently `/usr/share/nginx/html`.

Comment: Right "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app."' in the page source when I inspect the website in the browser (even though I for sure have js enabled in my browser).

What do you mean "code to do so is commented out"?

Comment: The text "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app" is included in the page source because **the webpage will conditionally display that text in the browser if you in fact have JavaScript disabled**. You need not worry about it being in the page source, as it is supposed to be there. Regarding the code being commented out, `COPY --from=build /app/build .` is the notable command you need. For whatever reason, StackOverflow's markdown renderer is showing that line in grey as if it is commented out, but it looks like it shouldn't be. Can you confirm if that line is uncommented?

Comment: It's not commented, as you said StackOverflow's markdown renderer is showing that line in grey for whatever reason.

Comment: it's not commented out, but it's inside `<noscript>` tags that mean it will only be displayed to the user *if* they have javascript disabled. If you're not actually seeing that on the webpage - which it seems you're not - you can literally forget about it. It's just how React apps are usually set up so that the very few users who might have JS turned off know that your app/site won't work unless they enable it.

Comment: Alright, but then why my React logo doesn't spin as it should if the entire js would be working? How it should look like https://youtu.be/3xDAU5cvi5E?t=4680